# Adding bootstrap js to react apps - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to implement bootstrap modal in my react app. **Bootstrap.css** is working pretty fine, but when i try to add `$("#thismodal").modal('show)` it gives me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).modal is not a
>   function

I have searched google and Stackoverflow, and got some answers but still not working.

I have added in my component:

```
import 'somefolder/jquery';
import 'somefolder/bootstrap';
```

> Not working

Added in my index.html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
```

> Not working as well

So, what am i suppose to do? I do understand that using jquery with react is not recommended. I can't use React-Bootstrap for some reason.

Comment: Why don't you try http://react-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: You should call jquery code after dom has been loaded, please check and let us know

Comment: I am calling it in componentDidMount. So DOM is already loading.

Comment: imo you dont need to import jquery. just add jquery on your script before your react and you should have the `jQuery or $` variable on your window.

Answer (score 0):

Starting of with a question, since if i remember correctly, I too have had this error. So here goes.

Have you declared the jquery in your react app?

```
declare var $ : any;
```

also, id avoid using bootstraps own modal for many reasons, but the biggest one is to have better control over it. React has something called portals which lets you hook a component to a select tag in the html body (say your app is rendered at id="root", you can make a new div with the tag id="modal" and hook it up there).

Once you've answered my question I might understand your question better (unless that actually solves your problem :)).

Cheers!